# Creating a column of p values in the table1 package

Tags: r

I'm using the example given here to try to generate a column with p-values, however, my code didn't work... and the **original example from the package manual** doesn't seem to generate a third column either. I've been trying to figure out the issue and I'm at a loss. Anyone have any ideas?

Source: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html

```
library(table1)
library(MatchIt) 
data(lalonde)

lalonde$treat    <- factor(lalonde$treat, levels=c(0, 1), labels=c("Control", "Treatment"))
lalonde$married  <- as.logical(lalonde$married == 1)
lalonde$nodegree <- as.logical(lalonde$nodegree == 1)
lalonde$race     <- factor(lalonde$race, levels=c("white", "black", "hispan"),
                           labels=c("White", "Black", "Hispanic"))

pvalue <- function(x, ...) {
  # Construct vectors of data y, and groups (strata) g
  y <- unlist(x)
  g <- factor(rep(1:length(x), times=sapply(x, length)))
  if (is.numeric(y)) {
    # For numeric variables, perform a standard 2-sample t-test
    p <- t.test(y ~ g)$p.value
  } else {
    # For categorical variables, perform a chi-squared test of independence
    p <- chisq.test(table(y, g))$p.value
  }
  # Format the p-value, using an HTML entity for the less-than sign.
  # The initial empty string places the output on the line below the variable label.
  c("", sub("<", "&lt;", format.pval(p, digits=3, eps=0.001)))
}



table1(~ age + race + married + nodegree + re74 + re75 + re78 | treat,
       data=lalonde, overall=F, extra.col=list(`P-value`=pvalue))
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved problem:

(1) Uninstall Table1 downloaded from CRAN

(1.1) Make sure RTools is downloaded and installed https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ at first my PC was not recognizing the program, but after several tries I was able to execute it

(2) Reinstall version from github remotes::install_github("benjaminrich/table1")

(2.1) Make sure other packages such as xfun are also updated to the latest version